# Textual search for ForeignKey field in Django Admin

Tags: django, search, foreign-keys, admin

I apologize if this question has already been answered, but I couldn't find it anywhere else.

In my django project, I have foreignkey fields which have hundreads of options for selection.
The django dropdown default widget for foreignkey fields makes it really difficult to find the one I want.

I have crossed with the filter_horizontal admin option, which brings great selection functionality for many to many fields with a textual search field and two selectors.

I was wondering if there is a django built-in option or if any of you has found a solution that allows me do a textual search "on-the-fly" for foreignkey fields as in many to many fields specified in "filter_horizontal"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not anything built-in, but nothing stops you from writing a custom widget.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if anyone lands here: Today we can use [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) like this:

```
class MyRelatedClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']

class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ('related', )

admin.site.register(MyClass, MyClassAdmin)
admin.site.register(MyRelatedClass, MyRelatedClassAdmin)
```

where `MyClass` has a `ForeignKey`-field named `related`. The `name` field of the related model will be used.